# Construct an object while skipping the fields

Tags: typescript

New to typescript. I am trying to construct an object out of another object of an arbitrary shape:

```
  class Thing {
    a?: string;
    b?: string;
  }
  const input = {a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c'}
  const builtInput: Thing = {
    ...input
  }
  console.log(builtInput)
```

I am expecting

```
{a: "a", b: "b"}
```

but getting

```
{a: "a", b: "b", c: "c"}
```

I have tried this with `thing` being a type and an interface too. Nothing works. Am I expecting too much magic and need to write a custom constructor? Is there a typescript way to do this?

Comment: Imo this shouldn't compile, but does, and since both of `Thing`'s properties are marked optional, putting just about anything in `input` would compile. But to give a hint to the answer, typescript doesn't do anything for you except type checking, so you will have to assign the values by hand

Answer (score 0):

You should write a function, which will create an object with required keys. I think, something like this will be useful:

```js
// initial type
type Input = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: string;
}

// result type
type Build = Pick<Input, 'a' | 'b'>;

const getFilteredInput = <T extends {}, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, requiredVals: Array<K>) => {
  return requiredVals.reduce((acc, current) => {
    if (current in obj) {
      acc[current] = obj[current];
    }

    return acc;
  }, {} as Pick<T, K>);
  // Pick describes an object from T with only K keys
};

const input: Input = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: 'c',
};

const build: Build = getFilteredInput(input, ['a', 'b']);

console.log('build', build);
```

Comment: Well, the example I have provided is a simplification and the `input` might have tens of fields and the fields can be different every time. I care only for selecting a subset of fields that match the fields of my type.

Comment: Sounds like you need some function to do this